# How to obtain a signal/noise measurement from a video without a background control

Tags: error, signal-detection

I have a video with a periodic process that can be seen as a change in brightness of the frame. I am measuring the process by calculating the average brightness value of the frame and plotting it over time. My video looks like a star-field with stars pulsing in sync.

I would like to quantify my signal/noise but I don't have a background video with this process not happening. What kind of approach would be appropriate in this situation?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by "signal/noise" here? Are you talking about measuring the amplitude of the brightness fluctuations?

Comment: Yes. I can measure the mean and standard deviation of the brightness change easily. But I would like to quantify that is likely deviations due to noise. Maybe signal/noise isn't exactly the correct measurement. More generally, I would like to quantify how meaningful my signal is.

Comment: Sorry, but "meaningful" is too vague. If you have a specific question, I'll try to answer.